How to make vararg parameter which gets at least one argument?
I have the following code:
fun qwer(vararg x: String){
}

fun main() {
    qwer()
}

As you can see i can pass 0 strings to qwer function. Is there a way to make qwer function get at least one argument ?

What about changing the declaration so that you have at least one parameter plus the varargs?

Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63318839/kotlin-1-n-constructor-parameter/63363193#63363193

You could do something like this:
fun qwer(first: String, vararg x: String) {

}

So, calling qwer() errors out but qwer("hello") is fine.
